# Adjoint Algorithmic Differentiation: swap pricing

Tags: greeks, interest-rate-swap, numerical-methods, algorithm

I have tried to implement an AAD routine to price call options using the Black-Scholes formula, but my greeks are not quite agreeing with the expected ones, so I have decided to start with something a bit simpler.

Assuming that I know all the discount factors and forward points (so that that I do not need to use any interpolation routine), what would be the best way to implement an **IRSwap pricer** using AAD? Any particular points I should bear in mind?

Comment: A swap pricer is simpler than Black-Scholes??  Shameless plug, but I've implemented AD in Black Scholes https://github.com/phillyfan1138/AutoDiff/blob/master/test.cpp.  It may help you figure out whats going on...my guess is that the ERF functions wasn't properly overloaded.

Comment: Agreed with @user9403, starting with Black-Scholes is simpler. I remember having found some code examples of Greeks computation using AAD implemented in Matlab, just Google it!